# A way to add int value to textbox with a button click and then subtract from the int value with another button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to have a button click event add an int value to a textbox and then have another button click event subtract from the same textbox that I just added the int value to. The problem I'm having is that the subtract button enters a negative(-1) value to the textbox and if I click on the add button again it goes right back to the int value I had before clicking the subtract button. I just want the add button to add and the subtract button to subtract the in value. I'm very new to c# and I've tried a everything I've found online and I'm losing faith.

I've tried if statements, and some other methods I found online and nothing works.

This is the code I have now. The add button works fine, but the subtract button doesn't do what I want.

```
 private int a = 0;
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      a++;
      txtSummary.Text = a.ToString();

    }

    private void comboBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private int b = -0;
    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      b--;
      txtSummary.Text = b.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 variables if you want to perform 2 operations on one  **one** value?

Comment: Nat Pongjardenlarp I tried adding the subtract function to the same variable and it didn't work. I'm starting to think what I'm trying to do is not possible in Winforms.

Comment: I can assure you that you can do addition and subtraction in Winforms

Comment: Oh, I'm sure I can do addition and subtraction in Winforms, just not with this method.

Comment: Just get rid of b and perform all your math on the a variable.

Comment: Lars Tech I tried that first but I guess I did it wrong because it was major fail.

Comment: `major fail` doesn't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Major fail means that after doing it that way the add button worked but the subtract button didn't do anything when I clicked on it.

Comment: You didn't post "that" code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert whatever is in your TextBox to an Integer, then add or subtract 1 to that value:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSummary.Text = "0";
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToTextBox(1);
}

private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToTextBox(-1);
}

private void AddToTextBox(int changeBy)
{
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(txtSummary.Text, out value))
    {
        value = value + changeBy;
        txtSummary.Text = value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Integer in TextBox!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Idle_Mind that code worked to perfection